# Can't read saved html page

Tags: html, apache, osx-snow-leopard

If I save a html page like this one:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Lista immagini:
    </h1>
    <img src="http://imageshack.us/photos/immagine/399/scalauominifl0.jpg" width="200" height="300" />
    <p>Fine</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I give the .html extension (character coding UNICODE UTF-8), the next next time I open it with text edit, I don't see the source code, but I see the web page.
How to see the and edit the source code?

Comment: Use another text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Sublime Text 2 as a text editor.